# How do I dependency inject PDO to a service in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm working with a library in the vendor/ directory and designating it as a service within Symonfy2. The library has a dependency on a PDO connection -- how do I set up my service definition to pass that to the constructor?

I'm trying something like this:

```
services:
    timers.mysql.service
        class : Fmp\Timers\Record
        factory_service : doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
        factory_method : getConnection
```

Which is giving me errors. Any help appreciated. Note, the library I can't modify - it needs a PDO connection, not a doctrine entity manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
services:
timers.mysql.service
    class : Fmp\Timers\Record
    factory_service : database_connection
    factory_method : getWrappedConnection
```

That should give you an object extended from PDO.

Otherwise, you might just need to define your very own pdo object.  The database session handler used to have an example.  BTW, factory_service and method are depreciated.  Might look at using the factory item.